# C# form class event

Tags: c#, winforms, events

So I have two classes "SplashScreenForm" and "Program" and on event want to run "MainForm".
It looks like this:

```
public partial class SplashScreenForm : Form
{
    public event EventHandler<int> RaiseUpdateEvent;
    ........
```

and in "Program" defining class like this

```
static class Program
{
    static Form SplashScreen;
    static Form MainForm;

    SplashScreen = new SplashScreenForm();
    .........
```

but problem is that when I'm trying to access event it says that "SplashScreenForm" doesn't contain that event. How can I solve this problem?

```
SplashScreen.RaiseUpdateEvent += SplashScreen_RaiseUpdateEvent;
```

> Error says: CS1061 C# 'Form' does not contain a definition for and no accessible extension method accepting a first argument of type 'Form' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error says, that the **Class** called `Form` desn't have an event called `RaiseUpdateEvent`

Only the class `SplashScreenForm` have that event.

So you should define your field to be of type `SplashScreenForm`:

```
static SplashScreenForm SplashScreen;
```

**More advanced alternative:**

If for some reason you want your variable `SplashScreen` to be of type `Form` (may be you get the type from a library you don't control), you can actually still use it, because **you know** it's a `SplashScreenForm` when you call `new SplashScreenForm()`.

In that case you can **Cast** it to your type like this:

```
((SplashScreenForm)SplashScreen).RaiseUpdateEvent += SplashScreen_RaiseUpdateEvent;
```

Now you're telling the compiler that although it's declared as `Form`, it's really a `SplashScreenForm` and can be used as that - meaning the `cast` type do have a `RaiseUpdateEvent` event.

Comment: Thank you, it's funny so simple it was :D

Comment: Well, most questions are easy, if you know the answer.

Comment: YES you are totally correct, Cast also works in my application. Thank you so much! ^_^